# CloudFormation: Return ARN of Subnet

Tags: aws-cloudformation, subnet

Is there another way to get `ARN` of created Subnet Resource `AWS::EC2::Subnet` via `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function. Subnet resource only returns `AvailabilityZone, Ipv6CidrBlocks, NetworkAclAssociationId, VpcId`.

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html#aws-resource-ec2-subnet-return-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `ARN` of a Subnet is in the format arn:aws:ec2:**REGION**:**ACCOUNT_ID**:subnet/**SUBNET_ID**. By using intrinsic function `Fn::Join` you can generate the `ARN` of the subnet.

Example: `arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:767022272945:subnet/subnet-0d42d2235s3a2531d`

```
  !Join
    - ''
    - - 'arn:aws:ec2:'
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - ':'
      - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      - ':subnet/'
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: VPC-SubnetId
```

Comment: Outstanding answer! For completeness, if the subnet you're referencing is local to the current template, then you can use an arguably simpler expression `!Sub "arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:subnet/${Subnet}"` instead, where `Subnet` is the logical ID of the subnet being referenced in the current template.

Comment: God, why AWS? Just WHY. *Cries in CloudFormation*

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, as noted in the comment by @sigpwned, is to just use `!Sub`

Even if the subnet you're referencing isn't local to your template, you can still pass it in as a parameter to the template or import it like in the original answer if it is available to the stack.

```
!Sub "arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:subnet/${Subnet}"
```